# Sql individual SUM

Tags: sql

I'm currently collecting data from individual tables. I'm supposed to get my sum (amount*weight) For each shipment. However it gives me the overall sum*weight, which means I get the same result all the way down.

Here is the code I carried out:

```
SELECT SUM(Weight*Amount), Arrival_Date 
FROM Specifications, Shipment, `Product shipment` 
WHERE Specifications.Product_Code = `Product shipment`.Product_Code 
AND `Product shipment`.Shipment_ID = `product Shipment`.shipment_ID 
GROUP BY Arrival_Date
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be GROUP BY shipment_ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `GROUP BY` of your query:

```
  SELECT SUM(Weight * Amount), 
         Arrival_Date 
    FROM Specifications, 
         Shipment, 
        `Product shipment` 
   WHERE Specifications.Product_Code = `Product shipment`.Product_Code 
     AND `Product shipment`.Shipment_ID = `product Shipment`.shipment_ID 
GROUP BY `Product shipment`.Shipment_ID, -- <- try add this
         Arrival_Date
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more fair to do GROUP BY `Product shipment`.Shipment_ID and then group by date?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: you're quite right - your version is more readble. I've edited the post.

Comment: How do i avoid getting the result repeated like that?

Comment: @Avacay: you should check WHERE conditions (comment out SUM and GROUP BY and inspect the data returned) as well as GROUP BY fields (mayhaps you have to add something like Specifications.Product_Code there)

Comment: SELECT SUM(Weight * Amount) `Total Weight` FROM Specifications, Shipment, `Product shipment` WHERE Specifications.Product_Code = `Product shipment`.Product_Code AND `Product shipment`.Shipment_ID = `product Shipment`.shipment_ID GROUP BY shipment.Arrival_date, `product shipment`.product_code

The following code here, seems right! However the results which are correct are still being repeated 4 times! :s

Answer (score 0):

You should group by shipment_ID, not Arrival_Date.
I'm not sure but maybe shipment_ID needs to appear in the SELECT clause for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your are not grouped by shipment_ID to get sum for each Shipment_ID

```
SELECT SUM(Weight*Amount), Arrival_Date 
  FROM Specifications, Shipment, `Product shipment` 
WHERE Specifications.Product_Code = `Product shipment`.Product_Code 
  AND `Product shipment`.Shipment_ID = `product Shipment`.shipment_ID 
  GROUP BY Shipment`.shipment_ID ,Arrival_Date
```